# Cannot override settings to display bullets on items in unordered list

Tags: css, wordpress, pagelines

I'm working with Pagelines theme on a Wordpress site.

The default overrides hide the bullets and tweak the margins and padding.

I've been debugging the Firebug. Found the CSS. Redefined styles for the UL element and LI elements I want to show bullets for. They still won't work.

The website URL is http://royalaire.com/site/

The offending list is in the sidebar, a nested list in navigation links.

I want second-level indented items bulleted.

Default are defined as:

```
.widget ul li ul li {
    margin-left: .03em;
}
.widget ul li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding 0 2px;
}
```

I tried with the following:

```
.widget ul.children li.page_item {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ensured with firebug or web inspector, that rule your tried to add is not overriden by some another?

Comment: @kirilloid, yes. my code is normal and original has strikethrough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a CSS expert and I have some trouble figuring out which definitions you have written for that list, but I know that adding `!important` after a style definition will make sure that it overrides all parent definitions. try:

```
.widget ul.children li.page_item {list-style-type: disc !important;}
```

Comment: Arbitrarily adding variations of `!important` to a css declaration is not an answer, IMO.

Comment: I know and I agree, but I merely suggested it so that the asker can use it to determine whether he is working with the right selectors. I should have put more emphasis on that.